# IndexError: only integers, slices(`:`), ellipsis(`...`), numpy.newaxis(`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices. Python version 3.10.11

Tags: python

Can someone please explain, why I get this error?

`f[i]= func(x)`

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

My code is:

```
import pylab as p
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def func(x):
    return p.exp(-x)-x

root=fsolve(func,[0])
print("X_true=", root)

x=p.linspace(0,1,20)
f=x.copy()
for i in enumerate (x):
    f[i]= func(x)
p.plot(x,f);p.grid()
p.show()
```

I expected a graph to open but instead I got the error on line 12 (`f[i]= func(x)`). I tried changing `=` to `:` since the program would suggest it but it didn't work.

The version of python I have is 3.10.11

Comment: `for i in enumerate (x)` is the issue; you probably meant `for i, item in enumerate(x)`. `enumerate` returns a `tuple` of the index and the item itself; currently, `x` is this tuple, and you cannot use a tuple as an index in this case.

Comment: And then you probably mean `func(item)`

Comment: @RandomDavis I think you mean "`i` is this tuple"

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension: `f = [func(i) for i in x]`